# Java Socket... how it works?

Tags: java, port, serversocket

I have a question on Java sockets.

I'm trying to build a basic server-client connection in java using the net package classes. so to start with, I'm used the Socket class and created a socket attached to what will be the client using

address=  InetAddress.getByName(ip);
socket =  new Socket(address , port );

ip: is just a string representation of the ip address and port is a port number I specified to attach the socket to.

Now my question is, when I use the method getLocalPort() I get a different port number than the one I specified.Also, when I use the command 'netstat' on the command prompt I don't find the port number at which the socket is connected to in the list of active connections.

can anybody explain why is that?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That is completely incorrect. The accepted socket uses the same port number as the `ServerSocket.` It also doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @EJP The server socket and the client share the same local port, but I agree, it was probably running of topic, no sleep has the habit...

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, the server socket and the *accepted* socket share the same local port, and the client's socket has this as its remote port. None of this bears any resemblance to what you said, or are now saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> port is a port number I specified to attach the socket to

No it isn't. It is the remote port number to *connect* the socket to. One of the problems in your question is that you are using terminology incorrectly and therefore confusing yourself.

> when I use the method getLocalPort() I get a different port number than the one I specified.

No you didn't. You specified the remote port when creating the `Socket.` `getLocalPort()` returns the local port. They aren't the same thing. There is a way to specify a local port number as well, but you don't need it. That process is calling 'binding'. Neither 'bind' nor 'connect' is an 'attach'.

> Also, when I use the command 'netstat' on the command prompt I don't find the port number at which the socket is connected to in the list of active connections.

You should. You should see a line with the remote IP:port in the remote column, and the state as ESTABLISHED.

Comment: Thanks to all... Now it makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

That's because the port number you specify in `new Socket(address , port );` is the *remote* port number. For example, if your remote server had a socket open on port 8123 you wanted to connect to, you'd enter `new Socket(address , 8123);`.

The port number you're seeing in `getLocalPort()` and in `netstat` is the port number auto-generated for your local machine socket.